# Converting a JavaScript code using callbacks and RegEx method to equivalent code in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, .net-core

I've the below JavaScript code, that returned a function callback related to the user command, the user command could be used in different ways, hence RegEx is required:

```
(function (undefined) {
  "use strict";

  var root = this;
  var commandsList = [];
  var debugStyle = 'font-weight: bold; color: #00f;';

  // The command matching code is a modified version of Backbone.Router by Jeremy Ashkenas, under the MIT license.
  var optionalParam = /\s*\((.*?)\)\s*/g;
  var optionalRegex = /(\(\?:[^)]+\))\?/g;
  var namedParam    = /(\(\?)?:\w+/g;
  var splatParam    = /\*\w+/g;
  var escapeRegExp  = /[\-{}\[\]+?.,\\\^$|#]/g;
  var commandToRegExp = function(command) {
    command = command.replace(escapeRegExp, '\\$&')
                  .replace(optionalParam, '(?:$1)?')
                  .replace(namedParam, function(match, optional) {
                    return optional ? match : '([^\\s]+)';
                  })
                  .replace(splatParam, '(.*?)')
                  .replace(optionalRegex, '\\s*$1?\\s*');
    return new RegExp('^' + command + '$', 'i');
  };

  var registerCommand = function(command, cb, phrase) {
    commandsList.push({ command: command, callback: cb, originalPhrase: phrase });
      root.console.log('Command successfully loaded: %c'+phrase, debugStyle);
  };

root.fonixListen = {
    addCommands: function(commands) {
      var cb;
      for (var phrase in commands) {
        if (commands.hasOwnProperty(phrase)) {
          cb = root[commands[phrase]] || commands[phrase];
          if (typeof cb === 'function') {
            // convert command to regex then register the command
            registerCommand(commandToRegExp(phrase), cb, phrase);
          } else if (typeof cb === 'object' && cb.regexp instanceof RegExp) {
            // register the command
            registerCommand(new RegExp(cb.regexp.source, 'i'), cb.callback, phrase);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    executeCommand: function(commandText) {
      for (var j = 0, l = commandsList.length; j < l; j++) {
        var result = commandsList[j].command.exec(commandText);
        if (result) {
          var parameters = result.slice(1);
          // execute the matched command
          commandsList[j].callback.apply(this, parameters);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  };
}).call(this)
```

Below are some commands:

```
  var commands = {
    'hello :name *term': function(name) {
      alert('hello '+name+'');  // i.e. consider *term as optional input
    },

   'items identification': {
         'regexp': /^(What is|What's|Could you please tell me|Could you please give me) the meaning of (TF|FFS|SF|SHF|FF|Tube Film|Shrink Film|Stretch Hood|Stretch Hood Film|Flat Film)$/,
         'callback': itemsIdentification,
   },

   'ML SoH': {
         'regexp': /^(What is|What's|Could you please tell me|Could you please give me) the (stock|inventory) of ML$/,
         'callback': mlSOH,
   },

    'Report stock on hand': {
         'regexp': /^(What is|What's) (our|the) (stock|inventory|SoH) of (TF|FFS|SF|SHF|FF|Tube Film|Shrink Film|Stretch Hood|Stretch Hood Film|Flat Film)$/,
         'callback': SoH,
        },

     'Basic Mathematical Opertions': {
               // ?\s? can be used instead of space, also could use /i instead of $/,
                'regexp': /^(What is|What's|Calculate|How much is) ([\w.]+) (\+|and|plus|\-|less|minus|\*|\x|by|multiplied by|\/|over|divided by) ([\w.]+)$/,
                'callback': math,
              },
  };
```

At running the app, the `addCommands` command is executed, and based on the input command from the user, the `executeCommand` command is executed.

The above works very fine with me, but I'm moving to C#, and very new to it, so looking for help, at least guiding of some functionalities and tools in C# that can help me write something similar to the above.

**UPDATE**
More details about what I try to do, actually I've a form, where the user input his command by voice using HTL5 voice API, the API convert this voice into text, then this text i submitted to my app, where my app work start by looking into this text, trying to find the required command using the ReqEx, then execute the programmed function/callback that is mapped with this input command.

Comment: C# have same flow controls `if - else`, `for loop`. C# have `functions` and `classes`, collections `List<string>`, `Dictionary<string, Action>` as dictionary with function and C# have `Regex` too - it will be better if you show what did you tried and we can help with some specific problem.

Comment: @Fabio I updated my question to explain more the required, I think the `Dictionary<string, Action>` you pointed to, could be close to what I need, I'll search it and check. thanks

Comment: *"Converting JavaScript code to C# with RegEx"* - This title makes it sound like you want to use regex to convert JS to C#.

Comment: @nnnnnn I amended the title, is it more logic now?

Comment: @Fabio can you help here pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447264/c-sharp-using-regex-in-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using `Dictionary` at `using System.Collections.Generic;` and using `RegEx` at `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` along with the need of a function called `FirstOrDefault` availabe at `using System.Linq;`

I used `Action` instead of function `Func` as the callbacks in my case are do not return anything, i.e. they are a `void` functions, and because no input parameters provided, I used `Action`-delegate, and did not use `Action<string[]>`.

The working code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;  // for Dictionary
using System.Linq;  // for FirstOrDefault
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;  // for RegEx

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var input = "What's the meaning of Stretch Hood";

                    var functions = new Dictionary<Regex, Action>
                    {
                        {new Regex("/^(What is|What's|Could you please tell me|Could you please give me) the meaning of (TF|FFS|SF|SHF|FF|Tube Film|Shrink Film|Stretch Hood|Stretch Hood Film|Flat Film)$/"),
                             itemsIdentification},
                        {new Regex("/^(What is|What's|Could you please tell me|Could you please give me) the (stock|inventory) of ML$/"),
                             mlSOH},
                        {new Regex("/^(What is|What's) (our|the) (stock|inventory|SoH) of (TF|FFS|SF|SHF|FF|Tube Film|Shrink Film|Stretch Hood|Stretch Hood Film|Flat Film)$/"),
                             SoH},
                        {new Regex("/^(What is|What's|Calculate|How much is) ([\w.]+) (\+|and|plus|\-|less|minus|\*|\x|by|multiplied by|\/|over|divided by) ([\w.]+)$/"),
                             math},
                    };
            functions.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key.IsMatch(input)).Value?.Invoke();    // This will execute the first Action found wherever the input matching the RegEx, the ?. means if not null ([Null-conditional Operators][1])
// or 
            Action action;
            action = functions.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key.IsMatch(input)).Value;
            if (action != null)
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                // No function with that name
            }
        }

        public static void itemsIdentification()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Fn 1");
        }

        public static void mlSOH()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Fn 2");
        }
        public static void SoH()
        {

        }
        public static void math()
        {

        }
    }
}
```